# How do I store referral code variables to iphone without app installed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Is it possible to store data to the phones memory without having your mobile app installed? Trying to implement a referral program and it would be ideal to save the referral code into memory and be able to be retrieved upon installation of the app. This would save the user the trouble of manually submitting the referral code. Any advice/suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: But at which point would the referral be saved, and by whom, if there is no app installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think deep link installs is the way to go here. [Branch.io](http://branch.io) is a good option.

Comment: Branch iOS referral docs: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branch-Integration-Guides/blob/master/ios-referral-guide.md